# Why does sed not process all occurrences?

Tags: sed

Or: How do I get sed to replace all occurrences?

```
$ echo ":::::::" |sed -e 's/::/:0:/g'
:0::0::0::
```

I would expect/want the output to be
:0:0:0:0:0:0:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Because once `::` seen, next `::` pattern doesn't contain last `:` of 1st pair!

Your string is parsed as `::` replaced by `:0:`, then `::`, `::` and `:`. So there are 3 `::` followed by `:`. This could be replaced by *`:0::0::0::`*. The operation seem correct!

So operation have to be done two time to ensure all `::` pair will be modified.

## [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) first

As requested, I answer by using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) first and because `sed` is the more efficient tool for this operation on big streamed files. See [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) further, more efficient for *variables* and small files.

### *hardcoding* two steps

Simply:

```
echo ":::::::" | sed -e 's/::/:0:/g;s/::/:0:/g'
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

Like many programmer (publishing here) this solution was not the first I was thinked about. **Anyway, for this problem, *hardcoding* two step is the more efficient solution!**

### *loop* now

Because I hate to do *hardcoding*, the first solution I found was to do a *loop* until all `::` pair will be changed:

So we have to add a `branch` condition:

```
echo ":::::::" |sed -e ':a;s/::/:0:/;ta'
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

`t` statment *branch* to `:a` label if last `s///` operation does some modification.

So `sed` will loop over whole line while `::`  will be found.

Note I've supressed `g` switch, but this will make more loop over line. Compare (I use lower `l` [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command to dump current line. see `info sed` for more informations regarding this):

```
echo ":::::::" |sed -e ':a;s/::/:0:/;l;ta'
:0::::::$
:0:0:::::$
:0:0:0::::$
:0:0:0:0:::$
:0:0:0:0:0::$
:0:0:0:0:0:0:$
:0:0:0:0:0:0:$
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

with 6 loop (1 by `0` added), and

```
echo ":::::::" |sed -e ':a;s/::/:0:/g;l;ta'
:0::0::0::$
:0:0:0:0:0:0:$
:0:0:0:0:0:0:$
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

where 2 loop will do the whole job.

## [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) now.

Of course this could be done by using a lot of different tools like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)...

But this could be done in a very efficient way, by using ***pure bash***:

```
var=':::::::'
echo ${var//::/:0:}
:0::0::0::
```

With the same problem!

### *hardcoded*

```
var=':::::::'
var=${var//::/:0:}
var=${var//::/:0:}
echo $var
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

In a `read` loop:

```
echo >testfile ':::::::'
while read -r var ;do
    var=${var//::/:0:}
    echo "${var//::/:0:}"
done <testfile
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *loop*

So by doing a loop, this could look like:

```
var=':::::::'
while [ "$var" != "${var//::/:0:}" ] ;do
    var="${var//::/:0:}"
done
echo "$var"
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

As this don't have to *fork* to another binary, this could be quicker.

And if doing translation two time seem too much, you could write this:

```
var=':::::::'
while tmpvar="${var//::/:0:}" ; [ "$var" != "$tmpvar" ] ;do
    var="$tmpvar"
done
echo $var
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

Show steps:

```
var=':::::::'
while
  tmpvar="${var//::/:0:}"
  [ "$var" != "$tmpvar" ]
  do
    var="$tmpvar"
    printf 'Step: \047%s\047\n' "$tmpvar"
done
Step: ':0::0::0::'
Step: ':0:0:0:0:0:0:'

echo $var
:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

Or if you drop 1st `/` to do only 1 modification by step:

```
var=':::::::'
while
  tmpvar="${var/::/:0:}"
  [ "$var" != "$tmpvar" ]
  do
    var="$tmpvar"
    printf 'Step: \047%s\047\n' "$tmpvar"
done
Step: ':0::::::'
Step: ':0:0:::::'
Step: ':0:0:0::::'
Step: ':0:0:0:0:::'
Step: ':0:0:0:0:0::'
Step: ':0:0:0:0:0:0:'
```

But this become *slower*!

Comment: I had same `sed` answer posted about 13 min ago

Comment: @anubhava Yes, You anwered while I was writing the explanation... ;-)

Comment: @anubhava Thinking about, It's more rational to *hardcode* two steps! See my edit!

Answer (score 2):

You may use a label and jump instruction in `gnu-sed`:

```sh
echo ":::::::" | sed ':a; s/::/:0:/g; ta'

:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

Or using POSIX `sed`:

```sh
echo ":::::::" | sed -e ':a' -e 's/::/:0:/g; ta'
```

Or using `awk`:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} {for (i=2; i<NF; ++i) $i="0"} 1' <<< ':::::::'

:0:0:0:0:0:0:
```

Answer (score 2):

When `sed` replaces `::` with `:0:`, the next match doesn't start with the final `:` of the previous match, but with the following colon.

You can use Perl's look-ahead assertion:

```
echo ":::::::" | perl -pe 's/:(?=:)/:0/g'
```

`(?=:)` means "the following character is a colon, but it's not part of the match". Therefore, the next match can start with the following colon.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you could try following. Written and tested with shown samples. Simply globally substitute all occurrences of `:` `:0` once its done then substitute last occurrence of `0` with null.

```
echo ":::::::" | awk '{gsub(/:/,"&0");sub(/0$/,"")} 1'
```